# lock file or partition for read and write systemcalls

Tags: linux, locking, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I need to know how to write a system call that blocks(lock) and unblocks(unlock)  an archive(inode) or a partition(super_block) for read and write functions.

Example: these function are in fs.h
**lock_super(struct super_block *);**
**unlock_super(struct super_block *);**

How to obtain the super_block (/dev/sda1 for example)?

Answer (score 2):

The lock_super and unlock_super calls are not meant to be controlled directly by the user level processes. It is only meant to be called by the VFS layer, when a operation(operation on inode) on the filesystem is called by the user process. If you still wish to do that, you have to write your own device driver and expose the desired  functionality(locking unlocking of the inode) to the user level.

There are no current system calls that would allow you to lock, unlock inodes. There are many reasons why it is not wise to implement new system call, without due consideration. But if you wish to do that, you would need to write the handler of your own system call in the kernel. It seems you want fine-grain control over the file-system, perhaps you are implementing user-level file-system.

For the answer on how to get the super_block, every file-system module registers itself with the VFS(Virtual File System). VFS acts as a intermediate layer between user and the actual file-system. So, it is the VFS that knows about the function pointers to the lock_super and unlock_super methods. The VFS Superblock contains the "device info" and "set of pointers to the file-system superblock". You can get those pointers from here and call them. But remember, because the actual file-system is managed by the VFS, you would be potentially corrupting the data.

Comment: Hello.You told about device drivers.We want to know about system call. I don't know what function returns the vfsmount struct , because we want to make a system call and  not a device driver.Because we want to block(lock) and unblock(unlock) through system call